# PyCharm is opening the wrong project

Tags: pycharm

When I click on `File > Open > [browse to my_project's directory] > OK`

Another project is opened, but not the one I requested. Why?

The window's title is pointing to `my_project`, but the project files on the left belong to another project.

The same thing happens when I use `File > Open Recent > my_project`

I've tried to do `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` but I've got the same behavior.

I use `PyCharm Professional 2017.1.2` on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit`

Is this a reported bug? How to fix that?

Comment: When you `ls` the project dir, do you see the files you expect? Are you sure the project hasn't been renamed? I can't test on Ubuntu, but I've never had a problem on Windows 8/10 or RHEL.

Comment: yes. projects files are ok. everything is in the right place

Comment: You've probably found a bug. I can't reproduce it, though. Have you tried reinstalling pycharm?

Comment: I had this happen to me too. I fixed it by searching for the name of the project in `C:\Users\my_username\.PyCharm2017.1` then I went through the xml files that had that project name and deleted the name in all of those spots. The problem was solved after that. Not the best solution, but it worked. (This is on windows, but the same thing can be done on ubuntu).